# Why useState function made of javascript does not work when the state is variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While I was studying react hooks, I saw an example of useState function that made of vanilla javascript.

```
function useState(initVal) {
  let _val = initVal

  const state = _val

  const setState = newVal => {
    _val = newVal
  }

  return [state, setState]
}

const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
console.log(count) // 1
setCount(2)
console.log(count) // 1
```

Although I declared state as variable, when setState function calls with newValue, the count does not change.

However when the state changes variable to function like below,

```
function useState(initVal) {
  let _val = initVal

  const state = () => _val

  const setState = newVal => {
    _val = newVal
  }

  return [state, setState]
}

const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
console.log(count()) // 1
setCount(2)
console.log(count()) // 2
```

the count starts to change.

Is this happening because whenever count function calls, it references changed value of _val by setState function using closure? and How can I explain how react hooks work using closure in javascript?

Comment: have you reviewed the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you are getting new, distinct variables with copies of the data.

```
// simple explanation
const list = ['dog'];
const [animal] = list;
console.info(animal); // dog

// change the original
list[0] = 'cat';

// output
console.info(list[0], animal); // cat, dog
```

Even if you refactor as below to use `let` and update correctly, you will not get the original value as there is no reference to it.

```js
function useState(initVal) {
  let state = initVal

  const setState = newVal => {
    state = newVal;
  }

  return [state, setState];
}

const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
console.log(count); // 1
setCount(2);
console.log(count); // 1

// simple explanation
const list = ['dog'];
const [animal] = list;
console.info(animal);;

list[0] = 'cat';
console.info(list[0], animal);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Although I declared state as variable

Actually, you didn't. You declared it as a const.

The first returns the value of a variable. Plain and simple. It happens to be `1`. The value is copied, you cannot change it. (Obviously you can change what count is set to, but you cannot change `1`).

The second returns a function. That function forms a closure over `_val`. `_val` isn't evaluated until `count()` is called. Each time it's called, it gets the value of `_val` and returns it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

Because you are rebinding it on this line

```
const state = _val
```

State becomes a constant frozen with initial value

```
return [_val, setState]
```

Change it to this and you will get what you would have expected